# Java chaining map methods and using optional

Tags: java, dictionary, nullpointerexception, option-type, method-chaining

I am using Java 8
`method1()` -> returns a `Map<String,Map<String,Set<String>>>`.

If I chain the method calls this way -> `method1().get("A").get("B")` a `NullPointerException` could happen.
So I am using the following strategy to avoid using the traditional `if( != null)` code:
`Optional.ofNullable(method1()).map(x -> x.get("A")).map(y -> y.get("B"))` but the this code return an `Optional` and I need that returns the `Set<String>`.
How can I cast it, and in case of `null` (in the case of the get methods returns null) how returns `null`?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Simply chain another `.orElse(null)` ...

Comment: But do you really find that chaining of `Optional` methods more readable than a bunch of if-then-elses?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Polishing the code by gamgoon a little bit:

```
    Set<String> result = Optional.of(method1())
            .map(x -> x.get("A"))
            .map(y -> y.get("B"))
            .orElse(Collections.emptySet());
    System.out.println(result);
```

Output in case either key is not in a map where looked up:

> []

You may recognize the result of printing an empty collection. In places where you want a collection, you should not accept a `null`. Use an empty collection to signify that there are no elements. In the same vein I have assumed that your `method1()` may return an empty map but not `null`. So we don’t need `ofNullable()` when converting into an `Optional` — the simple `of()` is fine.

Answer (score 1):

use orElse like

```
    Set<String> result = Optional.ofNullable(method1())
                    .map(x -> x.get("A"))
                    .map(y -> y.get("B"))
                    .orElse(null);
```