# Use Java 8 Optional features in the multiple null conditions

Tags: java, java-8, optional-chaining

Use **Java 8 Optional features in the multiple null conditions**

The conditions is

```
Optional<Payee> payee = Optional.ofNullable(paymtTrans.getPayee());
    
    if (payee.isPresent()
            && payee.get().getPayeeAcc() != null
            && payee.get().getPayeeAcc().size() > 0
            && payee.get().getPayeeAcc().get(0).getBnk() != null
            && payee.get().getPayeeAcc().get(0).getBnk().getBnkCtryCode() != null) {
        String ctryCode = payee.get().getPayeeAcc().get(0).getBnk().getBnkCtryCode();
    }
```

*The requirement is to use Java 8 features without checking the null values!!*

Need to get the ctryCode??

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Java chaining map methods and using optional](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69915682/java-chaining-map-methods-and-using-optional)

Comment: No, it's a v basic question, not related to my problem.

Comment: Please specify exactly what is returned from your `getPayeeAcc()` call.

Comment: Of course, you could add a `public Optional<String> getPrimaryBankCountryCode()` method to the Payee class, which make this look a lot cleaner.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just use `Optional.map(mapperFunction)`. If `mapperFunction` returns null, then `.map` returns an empty Optional:

```
Optional<Payee> payee = Optional.ofNullable(paymentTransaction.getPayee());
Optional<String> mayBeCountryCode = 
    payee
        .map(Payee::getPayeeAccounts)
        .filter(banks -> banks.size() > 0)
        .map(banks -> banks.get(0))
        .map(BankHolder::getBank)
        .map(Bank::getBankCountryCode);
```

**UPD.**
You can do it more elegant with taking stream of banks:

```
Optional<Payee> payee = Optional.ofNullable(paymentTransaction.getPayee());
Optional<String> mayBeCountryCode = 
    payee
        .map(Payee::getPayeeAccounts)
        .map(Collection::stream)
        .flatMap(Stream::findFirst)
        .map(BankHolder::getBank)
        .map(Bank::getBankCountryCode);
```

Then you can use `mayBeCountryCode`, for example, like that:

```
    mayBeCountryCode.ifPresent(countryCode ->
            // do whatever with a non-null string
    );

    String countryCode = mayBeCountryCode.orElse("none");
    String nullableCountryCode = mayBeCountryCode.orElse(null);
```

Comment: How to get the getPayeeAccounts() and choose the first Account only??

Comment: According to your code, getPayeeAccounts() is a method of `Payee` class and it is called here: `.map(Payee::getPayeeAccounts)`

Comment: Excellent Answer, clever. I would add a mention that if the programmer wants to return a string with a special signal value like “none” rather than return an `Optional<String>`, they could add one more call ([`Optional.orElse`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Optional.html#orElse(T))) to the chain: `.orElse( "none" )`

Comment: Excellent and v quick

Comment: I would change `banks->banks.size() > 0` to `banks->!banks.isEmpty()` as imho, it more describes what you are checking.

Comment: How to get the getPayeeAccounts() and choose the first Account only?? – 
Ans - using the findFirst() method

payee.map(Payee::getPayeeAccounts).findFirst();

@Kishore_2021